# How can I import design files from adobe creative cloud?

Tags: html, ui-design, adobe-xd, creative-cloud

My client has shared design  on adobe creative cloud. I am a newbie please guide how can I use these files, I can only view them in cloud but I need to actually convert the design to code.
regards

Answer (score 0):

Just go through with these below attached Screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]